# Where is the api for retrieving user joined communities in Google+?

Tags: google-plus

I'm creating a tool for a person to login into their google+ account and to lists all communities they were created or joined. I had googling around for a day and read google+ api references, but I couldn't find any information on:

1. Url of the API for accessing user's created or joined comminities,
2. Request parameters to perform such query

My tool has already succeed to perform oauth login and get **access_token** and ready to make any API call, But now I'm stuck trying to find the right Url and requirements to perform the API call as I wanted.

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There currently is no API method to do this. If you would like to see such a feature added, you can star this [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=562).